# Google Street View dynamic motion walk real

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I was wondering if it is possible images from Google Street View to change without waiting to load, I want to do a walk as real and I do not want to see to every step  the image change.
It can be use preloaded images is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Google Street View Image API lets you load static Street View images.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/ for details.  You can preload these images.